# Using Subclass method when iterating through ArrayList of parent class in Java

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, instanceof

In this loop, I am iterating through an ArrayList of type `Entity`, which contains objects of type Entity as well as objects of type Projectile, which extends Entity. I want the below code to be executed if the object is an instance of Projectile. However, the `getVelocity()` method is only in the subclass Projectile, and not in Entity. So I am unable to compile the below code.

I can think of ways to work around this, such as using separate ArrayLists. However, the point was to keep all Entities within a global list rather than separate them. Is there a simple solution to this problem, or do I need to change the structure of my code?

```
for (Entity f: glo.getList()) {
           if (f instanceof Projectile)
              f.setX(f.getVelocity()/rawFPS);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to cast it as a `Projectile` for it to compile. Try this:

```
for (Entity f: glo.getList()) {
           if (f instanceof Projectile)
              f.setX(((Projectile)f).getVelocity()/rawFPS);
        }
```

This happens because java always checks the type that an object is declared as; In your case this is `Entity`.

You may want to add a `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` so that your IDE and anyone that reads your code knows that the unchecked cast is intentional.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be a loop that updates your entities in some way every tick of your game engine.

In my opinion, a cleaner solution would be:

```
class Entity {
  ...
  public void update() {}
  ...
}

class Projectile extends Entity {
  ...
  @Override
  public void update() {
    setX(velocity/rawFPS);
  }
  ...
}
```

I don't know your architecture, you may or may not need to pass `rawFPS` to `update()`. (as @Naveen quite rightly pointed out, this is not very clean, so avoid it if you can). Also, if your `Entity` is abstract with no functionality on its own, consider making it an `interface` in the first place.

Comment: +1 This is a good object-oriented approach. Let the objects update/render themselves when they know how to and they can benefit by using internal/non-standard API if necessary.

Comment: I hadn't thought about having independent update methods. I'll look into whether it's feasible or not given the rest of my code.

Comment: Hmm... passing `rawFPS` to all entities smells a bit odd since most `Entity`s will ignore it.

Comment: @Navin Well, that depends. In a game, most entities that have to be updated are updated based on the time that has passed, so really most of them will need `rawFPS`. But I agree with you: It's best to avoid that if you can.

Comment: Pass the updater and use a type-specific callback.  This will make it a double-dispatch pretty close to visitor pattern.

Answer (score 2):

even `if(f instanceof Projectile)` is true your reference is of type `Entity` which has no clue what you declared in your subclass and so the compilation failure

provide the blank method in `Entity` class with same signature and than `override` it in sub class and remove `instanceof` check, if that fits on your class model

or

use casting

```
if(f instanceof Projectile){
  ((Projectile)f).setX(..);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Entity` should really be an `interface`, with a `getVelocity()` method defined on it.  Of course you can hack around the issue and cast, but ask yourself what the right logical model is for what you're building.

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but I would guess that it is because an `Entity` may not have a velocity so it does not make sense to give it a `getVelocity()`.

Answer (score 0):

Seriously, Guys? instance of sucks. Every guide on Java tells you that.

There's something wrong here: you are looping through a set of entities and altering the internal state of a subset (the subclass instances) using another data item: FPS. If you don't have the FPS when the Projectile is constructed, having this outer class inject it later seems kind of random. Might be cleaner to just call a set on the FPS and have the update of the positional occur then.

The outer class should probably ask for just the Projectiles.

Comment: `instance of sucks` really? This question is exactly the kind of situation where you use `instance of`.

Comment: I tend to agree with Rob, instanceof does suck.  I didn't address that portion in my answer.

Comment: Well... why instance of suck?

Comment: Because it's not object oriented.  If you're using instance of, your model is flawed.

Comment: Second link, dude: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=31 from Google.

Comment: @Rob That is not really a reason; It only says that it can be avoided in most cases. BTW can you explain the `call a set on the FPS` part? Do you mean something like `myEntity.setFps(fps)`?

Comment: Seriously, I am not going to put any effort into arguing against the use of instanceof. Career advice: don't wax poetic about your love for it in any future job interviews. It's really right behind goto in the pantheon of smelly things.

Comment: To clarify my comment: what I am saying is that the internal state of the Projectile class is it's business. You could trigger the computation of the velocity from when the FPS is set. So from the outside world, you just set the FPS and then inside the get method, the velocity is computed.

Comment: @Rob Well, my complaint is with the `you just set the FPS` part. Since you didn't answer, I'll just explain my reasoning: If you add a method like `setFps` to `Projectile`, you will have to cast the `Entity` as a `Projectile` anyway. If you add it to `Entity`, that smells even worse since it now has a method that is useless to most `Entity` objects.

Comment: Who said add it to Entity. I am saying only loop over the Projectiles, then move the computation of X INSIDE the class, that should not be on the outside.. ??